# React router v4 - wrong content of match object

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I've got the following code in my application:

**app**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="app">
    <Switch>
      <Route path={ getRoutePath('login') } component={ LoginSection } />
      <Route path={ getRoutePath('dashboard') } component={ AuthenticatedSection } />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**AuthenticatedSection component**

```
<div className="authenticated-layout">
  { authenticatedUser.isFetching === false &&
    <div>
      <HeaderContainer />
      <div className="wrapper">
        <AuthenticatedRoutesSwitch />
      </div>
      <FooterContainer />
    </div>
  }
</div>
```

**AuthenticatedRoutesSwitch**

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={ getRoutePath('dashboard') } render={ this.redirectToWorkspaces } />
  <Route path={ getRoutePath('workspace.configuration.create') } component={ ConfigurationCreatePage } />
 <Route path={ getRoutePath('workspace.show') } component={ WorkspaceShowPage } />
 <Route path={ getRoutePath('workspace.list') } component={ WorkspaceListPage } />

  <Route exact path={ getRoutePath('administration') } render={ this.redirectToUsersAdministration } />
  <AdminProtectedRoute path={ getRoutePath('administration.users') } component={ UserListPage } />
  <AdminProtectedRoute path={ getRoutePath('administration.oauth') } component={ OAuthListPage } />

  <Route path={ getRoutePath('trash.list') } component={ TrashList } />
</Switch>
```

My problem is that if I'll access `this.props.match` variable inside `<HeaderContainer />` component or also `AuthenticatedSection`, I'll get always the same default object (dashboard route probably) with empty `params`, `path: '/', url: '/'` even if I'm on different page. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you passing this.props.match to HeaderContainer?

Comment: @rooch84 Nope, I've got `HeaderContainer` wrapped in `withRouter`

Comment: And this.props.match is correct in AuthenticatedSection?  If so, it might be worth looking at withRouter some more.  Specifically this bit about it not being reactive: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#important-note

Comment: @rooch84 okay, `match` object in `AuthenticatedSection` is also filled up with 'dashboard' route properties and never changes.

Comment: I'm confused by your edit.  Do you have two switches?

Comment: @rooch84 yes, and it's probably the reason of the whole thing. Because <HeaderContainer> is inside the first switch (with login/dashboard routes). But idk, how to solve it, because I don't want to place <HeaderContainer> inside every route of `AuthenticatedRoutesSwitch` :-/

Comment: What about elevating HeaderContainer out of the switch, so it renders no matter the route?

Comment: @rooch84 it's not solution, because I cant display header if the user is not authenticated. Also I think it will not recognize the current route, it it will not be inside any switch.

Comment: I think that the only one right solution is to place `HeaderContainer` inside every page defined via `Route`. If anyone knows better solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to place `HeaderContainer` inside every page defined via `Route` in `AuthenticatedRoutesSwitch`. If anyone knows better solution, please, let me know.